# Verification of proof that if $f$ is continuous on a metric space $X$, the set $Z(f)=\{x\in X|f(x)=0\}$ is closed. (Baby Rudin Ex. 4.3)

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I just came across this problem in baby Rudin:

> Let $f$ be a continuous real function on a metric space $X$. Let $Z(f)$ be the set of all $p\in X$ at which $f(p)=0$. Prove that $Z(f)$ is closed.

Now it seems like a nearly trivial proof:

*$f(Z(f))=\{0\}$, where $\{0\}$ is clearly closed, so also $f^{-1}(\{0\})$ closed. But $f^{-1}(\{0\})=\{x\in X|f(x)=0\}$, which is exactly $Z(f)$. Therefore $Z(f)$ is closed.*

But I've not exactly known Rudin to have such simple exercises so I'm wondering if I'm missing something. And if I'm not missing something, I wonder what the relevance of such a simple exercise is.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes it's really that simple. I suppose it is an exercise since it can be quite a useful property.

Comment: The inverse of a closed set under any continuous map is closed.